# how to convert different length of bits into byte array?

Tags: c, embedded, compression, bit-manipulation, byte

I am currently working on a project where I have to implement Elias Gamma coding for an Embedded system (STM32F405 programming using C).
The main priority is efficiency and speed of the code thus I implenmented a lookup table for the Elias Gamma coding which contains bits values and number of bits for each "bit array" (I am using uint32_t for symbols and uint8_t for lengths).
However I am having trouble converting these bits to byte array. Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

For three symbols -> 0b0001001 (bits length 7), 0b011 (bits length 3), b000010001 (bits length 9) I have to get 0b0001001011000010001 thus 0x12 0xC2 0x20 as a byte array to transfer the data through a communication channel like USART.

What confuses me is, bit symbols being different length and "append" process that has to be applied to the bits in a platform that uses bytes as smallest data structure.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Edit:
For clarity I am trying to append 4096 "bit array" to X number of bytes. X number depends on the total number of bits appended (which is unknown while prossessing).

Comment: Are you familiar with bit shifting and bit masking? It looks like you just need to concatenate these various bit values together, right?

If you have to transmit this through USART, then that should be your bottleneck. Spending some time on bit shifts shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Will the number of bits always be at most 32?

Comment: Do the bytes need to be placed in memory? If so, is this a little-endian or big-endian system

Comment: @ikegami From the question it looks like the bits are packed into a sequence of 8-bit bytes starting from the most significant end of each source field downwards, and the most significant end of each destination byte downwards, with zero padding bits at the least significant end of the last destination byte if required.

Comment: Can each source symbol be represented as a single value of an unsigned integer type and a length? That will definitely be possible if each symbol is no more than 64 bits long.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with bit shifting and bit masking. I tried to write something but it became too complex too quickly so I trashed it. Therefore I asked if there is a simple way/solution to do this. @JohnFilleau.  Bits are stored as 32bits but the number of meaningful bits are variable. For example 0b0001001 stored as 0b00000000000000000000000000001001 and in other variable I hold the length of the meaningful bits like 7 for the 0b0001001. Bytes will be transmitted through a communication channel but before that they will be stored in ram. STM32F405 is little endian.

Comment: @Ian Abbott, That's the desired output byte order. I asked about the machine's byte order, which could be different.

Comment: @ikegami The question says the output is a "byte array" (presumably 8-bit bytes). So the length of the output in bytes will be the sum the bit lengths plus 7, divided by 8.

Comment: @user19402326, You missed one of questions. Can the total number of bits you're combining exceed 32? (Your example uses 7+3+9 <= 32, but you imply this is variable when you said you had lengths in uint8_t objects.)

Comment: @Ian Abbott, That doesn't answer my question. I asked what's the maximum that formula can give. If the byte array fits in a register, it presents additional solutions.

Comment: Can the total number of bits you're combining exceed 32? Yes they can. I was tryning to apply this to 4096 symbols (like 0b0001001) to bytes.  @ikegami

Comment: That does complicate things! :) gimme a bit

Comment: This can be done simply (though perhaps not most efficiently) using the Cortex-M4's bit-bandung feature.  You simply add the bits one at a time to the bit-band region, and they appear in the normal memory as a byte array.  Not portable to non Cortex-M3/4, but does make the code very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution requires:

```c
// Returns false if nothing left.
int get_next_bits( uint8_t *len, uint32_t *bits );

// Sends the first `output_len` bytes pointed by `output`.
send_buffer( uint16_t output_len, const uint8_t *output );

// Allocated memory or array large enough for output.
// See below if this can't be guaranteed.
uint8_t *buf;
```

Solution:

```c
uint16_t output_len = 0;
uint8_t *output = buf;     // Assumed to be large enough. But see below.
uint8_t available = 0;     // Number of unassigned bits in `*output`.
uint32_t bits;             // Bits to add to output.
uint8_t unassigned;        // Number of bits (left) in `bits`.

while ( get_next_byte( &unassigned, &bits ) ) {
   while ( unassigned > 0 ) {
      if ( available == 0 ) {
         // We need another byte of output.
         // `output` already points to this byte.
         ++output_len;
         *output = 0;
         available = 8;
      }

      if ( available <= unassigned ) {
         // We get here, for example, when we have
         // 5 bits to insert but only 3 bits available in current output byte.
         // So we shift the unassigned bits by 2 to place into position.
         // And we're left with 0 available bits and 2 unassigned bits.
         // We can't forget to "remove" from `bits` the 3 bits we assigned.
         uint8_t shift = unassigned - available;
         *output |= bits >> shift;
         unassigned = shift;
         bits &= ~( ( (uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF ) << unassigned );
         available = 0;
         ++output;
      } else {
         // We get here, for example, when we have
         // 3 bits to insert and 5 bits available in current output byte.
         // So we shift the unassigned bits by 2 to place into position.
         // And we're left with 2 available bits and 0 unassigned bits.
         uint8_t shift = available - unassigned;
         *output |= bits << shift;
         unassigned = 0;
         available = shift;
      }
   }
}

send_buffer( output_len, output );
```

The `available == unassigned` case can be handled specially if desired.

```c
if ( available == unassigned ) {
   // We get here, for example, when we have
   // 5 bits to insert and 5 bits available in current output byte.
   // We're left with 0 available bits and 0 unassigned bits.
   *output |= bits;
   unassigned = 0;
   available = 0;
   ++output;
}
```

---

If you can't guarantee a buffer large enough to hold all the bits, replace

```c
if ( available == 0 ) {
   // We need another byte of output.
   // `output` already points to this byte.
   *output = 0;
   available = 8;
   ++output_len;
}
```

with

```c
if ( available == 0 ) {
   // We need another byte of output.
   // `output` already points to this byte.

   if ( output_len == buf_size ) {
      // Buffer is full, so send and empty it.
      output -= buf_size;
      output_len = 0;
      send_buffer( buf_size, output );
   }

   *output = 0;
   available = 8;
   ++output_len;
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer. Documenting a few variables is insufficient.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Explanation of what it does is found in the OP. I could copy, but there's no point to that.

Comment: The posted question may tell us something about what the desired end result is, but it does not tell us how the code in this answer works or demonstrate how it provides the desired end result. Code without explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, It uses shifts. That's pretty obvious. It has to use shifts. The question therefore asks how to shift. I showed how to shift.

Comment: ...but added a few more comments.

Comment: Thank you! This works beautifully. After seeing the simplicity of your solution, I realized how much I had overcomplicated things in my own solution. @ikegami

Comment: @ikegami after checking code with my whole dataset there seems to be slight problem in line " bits &= 0xFF >> ( 8 - unassigned );".  By problem I mean if "unassigned = 23" then this result gives negative value.  Thus result becomes unpredictable. Can you suggest something so that I can correct this? Thank you.

Comment: @ikegami I changed that line with "bits &= ~(0xFF << (unassigned ));". Now it seems to be working.

Comment: Should be `bits &= ~( ( (uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF ) << unassigned );`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will copy a bit-field value of specified width up to 32-bits into a destination byte string in a big endian fashion. The destination is specified as pointer to the first byte of the destination string and an offset in bits to the position where the most significant bit of the bit-field is to be stored in the destination byte string. The mapping of offsets to corresponding bits in bytes is as follows:

- Offset 0 is bit 7 in byte 0.
- Offset 1 is bit 6 in byte 0.
- …
- Offset 7 is bit 0 in byte 0.
- Offset 8 is bit 7 in byte 1.
- …

The function contains a `while` loop that copies up to 8 bits at a time from the source bit-field to the destination. In each iteration, the number of bits copied is the minimum of the number of remaining, uncopied bits in the source bit-field value, and the number of bits from the current destination offset (in bits) to the next multiple of 8 bits.

For convenience, the the function keeps the remaining bits of the source bit-field left shifted so that the most significant remaining bit is at bit position 31. The `while` loop normalizes the destination position by adding the destination bit position divided by 8 to the destination byte pointer and setting the destination bit position to the remainder.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

/**
 * \brief Copy a bit-field into a string of bytes in big-endian order.
 *
 * \param dest Pointer to start of destination byte string.
 * \param dest_ofs_bit Offset in bits to location of most-significant bit
 *        of bit-field in destination byte string.
 * \param srcval Bit-field value as a number.
 * \param srcval_nbits Width of bit-field in bits.
 *
 * The destination byte string buffer is assumed to be at least
 * (\a dest_ofs_bit + \a srcval_nbits + 7) / 8 bytes long.
 */
void set_bitfield_in_bytes(uint8_t *dest, size_t dest_ofs_bit,
        uint32_t srcval, unsigned int srcval_nbits)
{
    /*
     * Move bit-field value to most significant end of srcval for convenience.
     */
    if (srcval_nbits < 32 && srcval_nbits > 0)
    {
        srcval <<= (32 - srcval_nbits);
    }
    while (srcval_nbits > 0)
    {
        unsigned int dest_shift;
        unsigned int nbits;
        uint8_t src_byte;
        uint8_t dest_mask;

        /* Adjust destination byte pointer and offset. */
        dest += dest_ofs_bit / 8;
        dest_ofs_bit %= 8;
        /* Extract up to 8 bits from srcval. */
        src_byte = srcval >> (24 + dest_ofs_bit);
        /* Assume all remaining bits in destination byte will be filled. */
        nbits = 8 - dest_ofs_bit;   /* Number of bits to fill. */
        dest_shift = 0;             /* No left shift. */
        dest_mask = 1u << nbits;    /* Bit-mask will be adjusted below. */
        if (nbits > srcval_nbits)
        {
            /* Not enough bits remaining in source bit-field, so adjust. */
            dest_shift = nbits - srcval_nbits;  /* Left shift. */
            nbits = srcval_nbits;               /* Number of bits to fill. */
        }
        dest_mask -= (1u << dest_shift);    /* Bit-mask of bits to fill. */
        /* Update bits in destination byte. */
        *dest = (*dest & ~dest_mask) | (src_byte & dest_mask);
        /* Shift remaining source bits to most-significant end. */
        srcval <<= nbits;
        /* Account for the number of bits copied in this iteration. */
        dest_ofs_bit += nbits;
        srcval_nbits -= nbits;
    }
}
```

Note that the function only modifies the specified bits of the destination byte string. If padding is required, the caller can either initialize the final byte of the destination with the padding bits before filling in the bit-fields that overwrite it, or can call the function with an extra bit-field to set the padding explicitly.

The following code tests the function with 4 consecutive bit-fields values including a padding bit-field. The bit-field values and their widths and offsets are:

- value 9, width 7, offset 0
- value 3, width 3, offset 7
- value 17, width 9, offset 10
- value 0 (padding), width 5, offset 19

The total length is 24 bits or 3 bytes.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void set_bitfield_in_bytes(uint8_t *dest, size_t dest_ofs_bit,
        uint32_t srcval, unsigned int srcval_nbits);

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t bytes[3] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };

    set_bitfield_in_bytes(bytes, 0, 9, 7);
    set_bitfield_in_bytes(bytes, 7, 3, 3);
    set_bitfield_in_bytes(bytes, 7 + 3, 17, 9);
    set_bitfield_in_bytes(bytes, 7 + 3 + 9, 0, 5); /* padding */
    printf("%02x %02x %02x\n", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2]);
}
```

Output:

```
12 c2 20
```

The function can still be used in a scenario where the destination buffer is a fixed size, the total length of the source bit-fields is longer than the buffer size in bits (buffer size in bytes multiplied by 8), and the destination buffer is flushed to some output device periodically. The caller just needs to be careful to neither overrun the buffer, nor send partially filled bytes to the output device. If the destination buffer is a cyclic buffer, it just needs 4 bytes (32 bits) of extra space past the end of the cyclic buffer to deal with bit-fields that write past the end of the buffer, and then it can move the excess bytes to the start of the buffer and adjust the destination offset.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "system" that takes as input a series of bits and lengths and outputs a series of bytes.

The user will iterate over a series of input bits. When the "system" has enough input to generate bytes, the user can extract them.

I'm imagining an API that looks like this

```
typedef struct {
    // holds a user-supplied buffer pointer
    char* buf_ptr;
    int buf_size;

    // pointer to usable data within the user-supplied buffer
    char* front;
    int bit_size;
} BitToByteMachine;

// initializes the BitToByteMachine
// The user supplied buffer must be at least large enough to hold the largest
// single input that the user will supply
void bit_to_byte_machine_init(BitToByteMachine*, char* buffer, int buf_size);

// Takes a uint32_t bitfield and a uint8_t num_bits
// Adds the bits into the current machine
// Returns the number of FULL BYTES available for extraction
// Undefined behavior if the buffer is too full to hold the data provided
int bit_to_byte_machine_insert(BitToByteMachine*, uint32_t bitfield, uint8_t num_bits);

// Returns the number of FULL BYTES available
// This can be called when there are still more pending calls to
// bit_to_byte_machine_insert(), for example to start transmitting data
// on a serial line before you've filled up the internal buffer
unsigned char bit_to_byte_machine_full_bytes(BitToByteMachine*);

// Returns the number of FULL OR PARTIAL BYTES available
// This should only be used after all data has been inserted and the only
// thing left to do is finish transmitting the data
unsigned char bit_to_byte_machine_full_or_partial_bytes(BitToByteMachine*);

// Extracts the next available byte
// If the next byte is a FULL BYTE, then will return the FULL BYTE
// If the next byte is a PARTIAL BYTE, then
// it will be zero-padded in the least significant bits
unsigned char bit_to_byte_machine_pop_byte(BitToByteMachine*);
```

Regular user interaction would look something like this

```
unsigned char my_buffer[4];
BitToByteMachine machine;
bit_to_byte_machine_init(&machine, my_buffer, 4);

while(there_are_codes_to_insert) {
    uint32_t next_code = get_next_code();
    uint8_t next_code_bit_size = get_next_code_bit_size();

    if (bit_to_byte_machine_insert(next_code, next_code_bit_size)) {
        while(bit_to_byte_machine_full_bytes(&machine)) {
            USART_transmit_byte(bit_to_byte_machine_pop_byte(&machine));
        }
    }
}

// no more codes to insert
// send the last bytes with padding
while (bit_to_byte_machine_full_or_partial_bytes(&machine)) {
    USART_transmit_byte(bit_to_byte_machine_pop_byte(&machine));
}
```

How does this API work for you?

Comment: `char` should generally not be used for bit operations because it may be signed, and that can cause issues with C bit operations. What is `buf_ptr`—is it the start address of a buffer the user supplied? If `front` points to the “usable data”, how do we know where the end of the data is? Why is `front` not always the start of the buffer? It `bit_size` the number of bits in the buffer measured from the start of the buffer or front where `front` points?

Comment: How does this answer OP’s question? They appear to have insufficient knowledge of how to use bit operations to put various strings of bits together. Giving them an API purportedly for some routines that would do that does not tell them how to implement those routines.